# How to reload only one component rather then whole page when active chain is changed?

Tags: metamask, wallets, ethereumjs, react

I have this react hook which reloads the whole page when the user changes network or account:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (window.ethereum) {
            window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", () => {
                window.location.reload();
            });
            window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () => {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
```

I want only one component to be reloaded rather than the whole page, because there are a few components that make calls to an external API when loaded, which I want to avoid.

How do I change the code so that only the desired component is reloaded on chain change?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the hook altogether reached the desired result

Comment: Could you give some more context? I'm using Rainbowkit and wagmi, I dont have any hook and my pages dont refresh on network change.